# Selecting item from dropdown using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to use Selenium to select Cars/data-option-array-index="5" from the dropdown below:

```
<!-- Activity -->
<div class="field clearfix">
  <label for="infosActivity" class="aligned">Main activity</label>
  <div class="contentinput">
    <select id="infosActivity" name="shop_activity" class="chosen">
      <option value="0" style="font-weight: bold" selected="selected">Please choose your main activity</option>
      <option value="2" >Animals and Pets</option>
      <option value="3" >Art and Culture</option>
      <option value="4" >Babies</option>
      <option value="5" >Beauty and Personal Care</option>
      <option value="6" >Cars</option>
      <option value="0">Other activity...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p class="userInfos aligned">Help us learn more about your store 
  so we can offer you optimal guidance and the best features for your business!</p>
</div>
<input value="full" name="db_mode" type="hidden" />
```

I've tried the following:

1. `driver.find_element_by_id("infosActivity").send_keys('Cars')` => error:

> *selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   element not visible*

2.`Select(driver.find_element_by_id("infosActivity")).select_by_visible_text('Cars')`=> error:

> *Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be
>   manipulated*

Whatever I try I  get *element not visible*.

Comment: Make sure that you're trying to handle correct drop-down.

Comment: I am 100% sure that I'm handling the right drop-down

Comment: Check whether `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("infosActivity")))` returns you `1`

Comment: print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("infosActivity"))) returns 1.

Comment: Post a link to the page. My guess is that this `SELECT` is backing another element on the page and is not actually visible since none of the answers provided have worked.